# Verificar se o mouse ou teclado foi acionado

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Estou iniciando no **Electron**, com isso preciso de uma ajuda.

Como faço para detectar se o teclado ou mouse foi acionado? Caso um dos dois não tenha sido mexidos em menos de 1 minuto executar um comando.

Obrigado.

Comment: Quer executar o comando após 1 minuto caso não tenham sido mexidos? Vc que fazer essa detecção apenas 1 vez?

Comment: Pode ser com JavaScript puro?

Comment: Olá Sam, seria uma rotina enquanto o PC estiver ligado. Não sei se apenas JS puro resolve, a DOC é nesse link https://electronjs.org/docs, mas ainda não sei como usar...

Comment: @Sam consegue me dar essa força?

Comment: Não sei, pq achei que era um website.

Comment: Tente essa lib, talvez possa ajudar: https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook